# IOS Website title from webview cookies

Tags: iphone, ios, cookies, webview

I want to retrieve website title from webview cookies of my application.

I am using:

```
NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
for (cookie in [storage cookies]) {
    NSLog(@"%@",cookie.properties   );

}
```

I am only getting the following fields in a dictionary:

2012-06-20 16:29:23.763 [4936:207] {
    Created = 361882697;
    Domain = "www.google.com";
    Expires = "2012-07-20 10:58:17 +0000";
    Name = MRES;
    Path = "/search";
    Value = "8ec208dd70991ccb:8a123708ae27c59e:b934e635fe6c1e21";
}

How can i save / retrive the website title Eg : Title Google , Url : www.google.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the page has been loaded in UIWebView, you can execute javascript on webview to get the title and then you can save it in the localstorage or the way you want to save.

Use UIWebView instance method `- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script`

To get title use javascript : `document.title`

Comment: I have to retreive all the webview cookies title in another view.

Comment: You can save the title in Cookies for every page that is loaded in UIWebView.